# Did Lakshmi (Sri Devi) know about the marriage of Sreenivasa and Padmavathi in prior according to Skanda purana?

Tags: venkateshwara, skanda-purana

Lord Vishnu took the form of Sreenivasa and resided near Tirupathi. He married the daughter of Akasa Raja, named Padmavathi.

According to the Skanda Purana, did Lakshmi know about the marriage between Sreenivasa and Padmavathi in prior to the occurrence of the marriage?